# How to prevent the closing of popup on backspace click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I made a simple popup screen. On button click I display the popup screen. On backspace it automatically closes.

I already use **data-dismissible="false"**. Although on backspace it still closes the popup. Is it possible to disable the backspace button?

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5anNC/6/

Please click the button to display the popup screen. On backsapce the popup dismisses.

```
function infoAlert(text) {
    var popupDialogId = 'popupDialog';
    $('<div class="aa" data-role="popup" id="' + popupDialogId + '" data-confirmed="no" data-transition="pop" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="b" data-dismissible="false" style="max-width:500px;"> \
                        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">\
<a href="#" class="common-button ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b optionConfirm" data-rel="back">OK</a>\
                            <h1>Info</h1>\
                        </div>\
                        <div role="main" class="ui-content">\
                            <h3 class="ui-title">' + text + '</h3>\
                            <a href="#" class="common-button ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b optionConfirm" data-rel="back">OK</a>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>')
        .appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);
    var popupDialogObj = $('#' + popupDialogId);
    popupDialogObj.trigger('create');
    popupDialogObj.popup();
    popupDialogObj.popup('open');
    popupDialogObj.find(".optionConfirm").first().on('click', function () {

        $(popupDialogObj).remove();
        return false;
       // popupDialogObj.attr('data-confirmed', 'yes');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could try something like:

```
$('body').keydown(function(e) {
    if($('#popupDialog').is(':visible')) {
        if(e.keyCode == 8) { // 8 is backspace
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }

});
```

[jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5anNC/14/)